# Post and get in the same script (HTTP request)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I am using this code right here:
**HTML code** (jsonexamplecss.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "adomaniname/phpselectdatawhere.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {

    var s = 256;
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "adomainname/phpselectdatawhere.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.send("limit="+s);
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out = arr[i].name 
        if (out = "0 results") {
            alert("0 results");
        }    
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    alert(out);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP code**(phpselectdatawhere.php):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['limit'])){
    $limit = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['limit']);
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM testget WHERE id='$limit'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["name"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }  
    $conn->close();
?>
```

I have a table named `testget` with `id, name` fields both `VARCHAR`. I wrote a script in order to do these things:

1. The HTML script sends data to the php script via http request and in this example it sends `limit=256`.
2. The PHP script gets the `limit=256`, puts away the number from the limit and stores `$limit =256`.
3. After that the PHP script searches if there is a `name` in the table whose `id='$limit'` and prints the `name` if it exists, else it echoes 0 results. The table `testget` has a row where `id=256` and `name=JohnDoe` so it can't echo 0 results.
4. After all this procedure the HTML scripts gets the echoed stuff and alerts them with JavaScript.

So in this case I want to have JohnDoe alerted in my HTML page but unfortunately nothing shows up. Could you please help me?

Note that the url and the database connection info are correct but as you can understand I don't want to show them.

Comment: Never going to work, because you're trying to deal with JSON in your JS code, and your php is dumping out plain text. plaintext != json.

Comment: Do you know an alternative way to do it?

Comment: json_encode your return values.

Comment: Or don't try to JSON.parse the response; it has no structure, it is just a text message. Simply alert that response, or pass it into the innerHTML of some DIV or value of some input element.